# Howto extend a plugin model class in CakePHP with "clean" classnames?

Tags: cakephp, model, extend

I'm currently learning CakePHP. I use CakePHP 2.2.3. I have succesfully "installed" a user management plugin. This plugin has a model class "User" and uses table "users". Now, I'd like to extend this User model in order to e.g. relate my own models to it, e.g. Posts.

I managed to to this with the following code:

```
App::import('Model', 'Usermgmt.User');

class MyUser extends User {
    var $hasMany = array('Post');
    var $useTable = 'users';
}
```

This works.

However, I don't like the fact that I have to call my Model class something like "MyUser". It makes everything very ugly and, maybe - theoretically - sometime I want to install another plugin that uses classname "MyUser". Is it somehow possible to use "clean" class names and prevent possible name collisions in the future..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible because CakePHP doesn't yet support namespaces. According to the [roadmap](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/development-roadmap) support for namespaces is planned for CakePHP 3.

Comment: Ah, thanks! This makes perfectly sense, that I didn't think of this myself! :)